# How to move language switcher outside of settings tab on mobile view Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I trying to move the language switcher on mobile devices to be in the main website menu instead of the settings tab (screenshot below):

[image]

I found some instructions on how to do that from the layout.xml file using

```
<move element="name.of.an.element" destination="name.of.destination.element"/>
```

However, I couldn't find the values for `element` and `destination` attributes.

Magento V. 2.3.5

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code which might help you.

Add `default.xml` file at following path

> app/design/frontend/ThemeVendor/ThemeName/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="default_head_blocks"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="store.menu">
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language_mobile" as="store_language_mobile" template="Magento_Store::switch/languages.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Magento\Store\ViewModel\SwitcherUrlProvider</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
        <!-- <referenceBlock name="store.settings" remove="true" /> -->
    </body>
</page>
```

If you don't want to keep `settings` menu in mobile then uncomment

`<referenceBlock name="store.settings" remove="true" />`

[image: Mobile Menu]

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in your default.xml file

Path :

> app/design/frontend/YourTheme/Package/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="store.menu">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Change Here</argument>
        </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```